# Stroke Scale reduction and redraw in android

Tags: android-canvas, scaling, ontouchlistener, redraw, stroke

Am trying to get the stroke data when the user scribbles on screen and redraw that same stroke on same location, in reduced size based on screen size of display. My issue is that this code works, it scales down striker but all scaled down strokes are connected which I don't want to be.

My ontouch code snippet:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, final MotionEvent event) {
     x = event.getX();
     y =event.getY();
/*  float x=(float) (xx*0.7);
    float y=(float) (yy*0.7);*/
    array_x.add(x);
    array_y.add(y);
    if(event.getPointerCount() == 2){
        timevar2 = event.getEventTime();
        float newx = event.getX(0);
        float newy = event.getY(0);
        float oldx = event.getX(1);
        float oldy = event.getY(1);
        mPath.reset();
        float equa = (float) (Math.pow(newx - oldx, 2) + Math.pow(newy - oldy, 2));
        float cscale = (float) Math.sqrt(equa)/100;
        float scaled = (cscale - old_scale);
        if(scaled < -0.1){
            if(scale > 0.1){
              scale -= 0.03;
            }
        }
        if(scaled > 0.1){
            scale += 0.03;
        }

        old_scale = cscale;
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    long dt = event.getEventTime() - timevar2;
    if(dt < 100){
        return true;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);
        Log.v("TOUCH=======start","X=="+x + "Y=="+y);
        invalidate();

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        Log.v("TOUCH=======move","X=="+x + "Y=="+y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up(x,y);
        Log.v("TOUCH=======up","X=="+x + "Y=="+y);
        //invalidate();

        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
         mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    for(int i=0;i<array_x.size();i++)
                    {
                        x= array_x.get(i);
                        y= array_y.get(i);

                        if(i == 0){
                            x=(float) (x*0.7);
                            y=(float) (x*0.7);
                            Log.i("ARRAYYYYYY", "X=="+x+"Y=="+y);
                            touch_start(x, y);
                            invalidate();
                        }else if(i == array_x.size()-1){

                            x=(float) (x*0.7);
                            y=(float) (x*0.7);

                            touch_up(x, y);
                            invalidate();
                            mPath.reset();
                        }else{
                            x=(float) (x*0.7);
                            y=(float) (y*0.7);

                            touch_move(x, y);
                            invalidate();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 2000);

        break;
    }

    return true;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {

    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
     if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
     }
    if (this.isErase) {
        erasePath(mPath, x, y, mX, mY);
        return;
    }
    PointF point = new PointF();
    point.x = x;
    point.y = y;
    newPoint.points.add(point);
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

}

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    undonePaths.clear();
    mPath = new Path();
    newPoint = new Stroke();
    PointF point = new PointF();
    point.x = x;
    point.y = y;
    newPoint.points.add(point);
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;

}
private void touch_up(float x, float y) {

    if (this.isErase) {
        return;
    }
    PointF point = new PointF();
    point.x = x;
    point.y = y;
    newPoint.points.add(point);
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    Pair p = new Pair(mPath, newPoint);
    this.Strokepaths.add(p);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean connected? Could you attach some screenshots on what happens now and what you are expecting?

Comment: Is your issue solved ?